# Setting turtles energy diminishing differently in different areas

Tags: netlogo, energy

In NetLogo I've got 3 areas:

```
to setup-patches


ask patches [ if pxcor > 6   
    [set pcolor yellow
    ]
  ]
  ask patches [ if pxcor <= 6
    [set pcolor green
    ]
  ]
    ask patches [ if pxcor < -6
    [set pcolor blue
    ]
  ]
end
```

I'd like 2 of my 3 different kinds of turtles to lose energy faster as they go (tick) in one of the areas, for example in `ycor > 6`.

```
set energy energy - 1 [ -6 if xcor <= 6]
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ask patches with [pxcor > 6] [set pcolor yellow]
ask patches with [pxcor <= 6] [set pcolor green]
ask patches with [pxcolor < -6] [set pcolor blue]
```

Then, if energy is a turtle variable.

```
ask turtles 
[
   if yellow = pcolor [set energy energy - 1]
   if green = pcolor [set energy energy - 2]
   if blue = pcolor [set energy energy - 3]

]
```